# Proving $u$ is harmonic with the Dirichlet Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry

I'm studying the Dirichlet problem in the Complex Analysis book from Stein and Shakarchi.

For the exercises I was a bit confused so I looked up examples and came across this [this useful page](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Complex_Variables_with_Applications_(Orloff)/11%3A_Conformal_Transformations/11.10%3A_Solving_the_Dirichlet_problem_for_harmonic_functions). I understand how they find/write the solution for $u(x,y)$ in the examples and also that you have to show that $u$ is truly a solution. But I am confused on how they show that $u$ is harmonic.

I know that if $f$ is a analytic/holomorphic function then Re$(f)$ and Im$(f)$ are harmonic. In the examples they use the logarithm, but I don't understand why they use it, how they use it and how they find the function $\Phi$ where $u = \text{Re}(\Phi)$.

Lastly, I don't see how exactly the theory in the book connects to the examples (chapter 8 section 1.3 The Dirichlet problem in a strip). I understand lemma 1.3, and see how they use that,

> (lemma 1.3: Let $V$ and $U$ be open sets in $\mathbb{C}$ and $F: V \to U$ a holomorphic function. If $u: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is a harmonic function then $u \circ F$ is harmonic on $V$.)

but I don't know how to solve the questions using the theory. Without seeing the examples from the link I would have not known how to find $u$ and how to prove that $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: they use the logarithm because the argument on the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$ is $0$ on the positive real axis and $\pi$ on the negative. what is your question?

Comment: I still don't understand why they use the logarithm. My question is how do they find $\Phi$ to prove that $u$ is a harmonic function.

Comment: I still don't get your question. In example 11.10.2 you understand why they use the logarithm?

Comment: No, not really. I don't see how they know that $u = Re(\frac{1}{\pi i} log(z))$. I think that $u = \frac{1}{\pi} \theta = \frac{1}{\pi i} i \theta = \frac{1}{\pi i} Im(log(z)) = Re( \frac{1}{\pi i} log(z)$. But I don't know why exactly they use $log(z)$. I'm also confused in example 11.10.3 how they make $\Phi$ and how they know to put in e.g. $log(z-x_3)$.

Comment: write $z=re^{i\theta}$ so $\log z= \log r+i\theta$ hence $\Re(1/(i\pi)\log) z=\theta/\pi$ which is $0$ on the positive reals and $1$ on the negative reals. Further as a real part of a holomorphic function defined on the strictly upper half plane it is harmonic on the strictly upper half plane.